# How to compine two webclient mono calls into one mono<ResponseEntity<>> call

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have two calls a() and b() and both return`Mono<String>`, the string is a json with different structures. I also have two methods that extract data from each json string. I want to combine the two into one object, lets call it AA.  What I started to write was

```
val aRes = a()
val bRes = b()
return aRes
       .map {
          str -> 
             AA(
              aa = extractAAFromARes(str)
              bb = extractBBFromBRes(bRes.block()!!) 
              )
       }
       .map { body -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(body) }
       .toMono()
```

I get an error on `bb = extractBBFromBRes(bRes.block()!!)`

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not 
supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2
```

how can I combine the two calls without getting the blockin error?

Thank you

es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not block reactive flow. Instead of it use operators like `Mono.when(aa, bb)` if you just want to wait until both publishers resolve or `Mono.zip(aa, bb)` that would return `Mono<Tuple2<T1, T2>>` in case you need results downstream. You could also consider `Mono.zipDelayError` in case you need special error handling.